# Summarise dataframe with correlation of variables based on multiple groups

Tags: r, dplyr, correlation, group

I'm working with a dataset that has two level grouping. Here I give an example:

```
set.seed(123)
example=data.frame(
  id = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20)),  # grouping 
  Grp = rep(c(rep('A',10),rep('B',10)),2),  # grouping
  target = c(rep(1:10,2), rep(20:11,2)),
  var1 = sample(1:100,40,replace=TRUE),
  var2 =sample(1:100,40,replace=TRUE)
)
```

In this case, the data is grouped by `id` and by `Grp`. I want to calculate the correlation of `target` with `var1` and `var2`. However, I don't know which is the most efficient way to apply this using a tidy approach and based on the groups.

I tried with `dplyr` approach. Like using:

```
example %>% group_by(id,Grp) %>% 
  summarise(cor(target,c(var1,var2)))  # length error
```

Or even creating a custom function and applying it. But this last only summarise all the data without grouping:

```
corr_analisis_e = function(df){
  return( cor(df[,'target'] , df[,c('var1','var2')]) )
  
}

example %>% group_by(id,Grp) %>%  corr_analisis_e() # get all the data at once
```

As output, I would expect to get something like a matrix or dataframe of 4 rows and 2 columns, where each row is a group (id and Grp) and columns are var1 and var2. Every value the result from the `cor()` method.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
example %>% 
  group_by(id, Grp) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(var1, var2), ~ cor(.x, target)))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id Grp     var1   var2
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 A     -0.400  0.532
2     1 B     -0.133 -0.187
3     2 A     -0.655 -0.103
4     2 B     -0.580  0.445
```

The grouping columns can then be removed with `%>% ungroup %>% select(var1:var2)`.

Comment: Much simpler that I thought. Thanks!